# making Socks5 proxy from Ubuntu VPS

Tags: scripts, proxy, vps

I'm trying to make a socks5 proxy from my ubuntu 16.04 vps but all the guides on doing so are outdated and i cant find any new programs.
I tryed dante-server_1.4.1 and dante-server_1.4.2.
Are there better programs than dante for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "but all the guides on doing so are outdated" What do you mean by that? The guides are created for a specific Ubuntu version. That does not make the guides outdated. It makes them perfect for a specific release. "Are there better programs than dante for this?"  You are asking for opinions and those type of questions are off topic on AU. Please provide what is not working for you in a given guide.  Setting up Dante is not too difficult but there is also Shadowsocks.

Comment: If all you need are the commands (or you can read russian ;)  http://renbuar.blogspot.com/2019/06/shadowsocks-with-cloak-plugin_14.html looks good for a 18.04 installation. "on doing so are outdated" You really do want to use an outdated guide (ie. one for 16.04).

Comment: @Rinzwind i've used this guide https://techlist.top/install-dante-on-ubuntu-16-04/ i followed everything changed interface name in config to "eth0"(my vps interface) added an user and tryed to login on my proxy with ios but i get no internet connection. the command "systemctl status sockd" says its running